# Where are stored the data of tags when the NfcAdapter discovers tag?

Tags: android, nfc, nexus-s

I have further questions:

-Where are stored the data of tags when the NfcAdapter discovers tag?

-Is it possible to get NFC chip Id of the phone (Nexus S) by software?

-Is it possible to consider website action as "Tag Discover"? I mean is it possible to do some action on a website which will do react my phone as if it has discovered tags?

Answer (score 0):

First, the data is stored on the tag. When you talk to the tag, usually an array with the response is returned by the method you used to talk. (such as tag.tranceive(byte[]))

Second, no. It is randomly generated.

Third, I don't know. I would search for other "intents" that the phone can generate. But there may be.